# top 10 rows in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

i have 2 tables .
abc(CID(pk), cname,)
order(order_id(pk), CID(fk), number_of_rentals)

i want to fetch top 10 customers based on number of rentals.

```
SELECT  cid, sum(no_rentals) as sum 
FROM orders 
group by cid, no_rentals
order by no_rentals desc;
```

how can i use rownum function in above query to fetch the desired output

Comment: Are you sure you want to `SUM` *and* `GROUP BY` the `no_rentals` column?

Comment: @Dai i want to fetch top 10 customers based on number of rentals so i think i have to do that

Comment: You just need to `GROUP BY` the `cid` column, you don't group by the `no_rentals` column because it's being `SUM`med for each `cid`. I suggest you read-up on how Aggregate Functions work when used with `GROUP BY` statements.

Answer (score 5):

Just wrap your query in:

```
SELECT * FROM ( your_query ) WHERE ROWNUM <= 10;
```

However, your query does not look like it is going to do what you intend as the `GROUP BY no_renalts` will mean that each distinct `no_rentals` value will be in its own group and you will not sum the values for each customer so you probably don't want to include it in the `GROUP BY`. Also, if you want to order by the total number of rentals then you want to `ORDER BY SUM( no_rentals )` (or by its alias) like this:

```
SELECT   cid,
         SUM(no_rentals) as total_no_rentals 
FROM     orders 
GROUP BY cid
ORDER BY total_no_rentals DESC;
```

Then you can apply the row limit like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT   cid,
           SUM(no_rentals) as total_no_rentals
  FROM     orders 
  GROUP BY cid
  ORDER BY total_no_rentals DESC
)
WHERE ROWNUM <= 10;
```